# Replace the text using jquery closest

Tags: javascript, jquery

The thing I have tried so far is

```
     <h3>This is what I want to display inside "ppname"</h3><a class="" href="javascript:" code="displayed">HO</a>
 <h3>Just for test</h3>
<div class="pp" style="display:none;">Not
    <div class="ppname"></div>
    <div class="ppcode"></div>
</div>
```

The Jquery

```
$('a[code]').click(function () {
    $('.ppcode').html($(this).attr('code'));
    $('.ppname').html($(this).closest("h3").html());
    $('.pp').show();
});
$('span.close').click(function () {
   $('.pp').hide();  
  });
```

The text in attribute code is displaying inside the div with class ppcode but the text in h3 is not displaying inside div with class ppname.
Thanks

Comment: `$(this).attr('coupon')` is wrong in your question there is no `attr` `coupon` in `a` tag

Comment: Corrected. Thanks for notifying.

Comment: If you check the [`.closest()` doco](http://api.jquery.com/closest) you'll see that it only searches up through parents, grandparents etc., it doesn't look at sibling elements.

Comment: Thanks something was unclear at my side. Now cleared. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `prev` instead of `closest` to display the sentence `This is what I want to display inside "ppname"` in the `ppname`-container:

```
$('.ppname').html($(this).prev().html());
```

Comment: Simple and Quick,just what I asked for. Here is a fiddle explaining all http://jsfiddle.net/43yjdvt3/